# How to use 誤認されます

Tags: passive-voice

How to say A was misidentified as B?

AがBと誤認されました or AをBと誤認されました?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but have different usages.

"AがBと誤認されました" is a simple direct passive statement:

> 息子が万引き犯と誤認されました。
>   My son was misidentified as a shoplifter.

"AをBと誤認されました" is an **indirect passive** sentence; i.e., someone else (usually the speaker) was (usually negatively) affected by this wrong identification.

> (私は)息子を万引き犯と誤認されました。
>   My son was misidentified as a shoplifter (and I was bothered).

In this example, failing to use indirect passive may sound like you're a little indifferent about your son's trouble.